# Check if route is valid in RequestStartup in NancyFX

Tags: c#, .net, rest, nancy, self-hosting

I have a self-hosted REST API in my wpf application, built using NancyFX. The application is used for updating firmware and running diagnostics on different consumer products that are connected to the computer with a USB cable.

A product must be connected to the computer in order to use the API. So I thought it would be smart to do this check in the overriden RequestStartup() method in WindsorNancyBootstrapper which means that the check can be done in one location, instead of in every module. It worked as expected. No modules will handle the request if a product isn't connected.

But this led to an unwanted side effect in the following scenario:

- A product is not connected to the computer
- The path is invalid

This will always return a 404 with a message saying that the device is not connected, instead of a "bad url" message. I could move the check to each module, but i'd hate doing so. What I want:

- If the url is invalid, no matter if there's a connected device, always return a 404 "Bad url" response without involving any modules
- if the url is valid, but there is no connected device, return a 400 "no connected device" without involving any modules

And I would like to do this in one place. I have looked around for a solution but I haven't found anything. I'm thinking that maybe my approach is a dead end. After all, I'm using the BeforeRequest pipeline which could mean that there's no way of validating the URL yet?

My method (simplified) looks like this at the moment:

```
protected override void RequestStartup(IWindsorContainer container, IPipelines pipelines, NancyContext context)
{
    pipelines.BeforeRequest.AddItemToEndOfPipeline(ctx =>
    {
        // TODO: Here I would like to check if the url is valid in order to be able to return a 404 "bad url" response

        if (!_hasConnectedDevice)
        {
            // ResponseBase is my base class for all my JSON responses
            var response = new ResponseBase(ctx.Request.Url, Messages.DeviceNotConnected);
            return new JsonResponse(response, new DefaultJsonSerializer())
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound
            };
        }
        if (!_deviceIsReady)
        {
            var response = new ResponseBase(ctx.Request.Url, Messages.DeviceNotReady);
            return new JsonResponse(response, new DefaultJsonSerializer())
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest
            };
        }


        return null;
    });

    // Catch all unhandled exceptions here.
    pipelines.OnError += (ctx, ex) =>
    {
        var response = new ResponseBase(ctx.Request.Url, ex.Message);
        return new JsonResponse(response, new DefaultJsonSerializer())
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError
        };
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can think of to do this would be to do something similar to what we do with security where you create an extension method on INancyModule that adds something to the pipline that checks if the device is plugged in and ready and returns the relevant status code if it's not, otherwise it just returns null, then in each module you want to only work with the USB devices you add:

this.RequiresUsbThings(); // Or whatever you want to call it :)

Comment: Yes, I could check for a connected device in each module, but I would rather perform this check in one central place if possible. :)

Comment: I know, but I don't think there's any way to do that and also check to see if the route is valid, hence my suggestion :)